# Maximum number of sides of a convex polygon

Tags: geometry

Exactly 3 of the interior angles of a convex polygon are obtuse. What is the maximum number of sides?

Comment: Does your definition of "convex" allow for interior angles of $180$ degrees?

Comment: @Barry Cipra Yes.

Comment: Is an angle of $180$ degrees considered obtuse (i.e., greater than $90$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that the maximum number of sides is 6.

The sum of the interior angles of a convex polygon of $n$ sides is $(n-2)180^{\circ}$. Hence the sum of the exterior angles is $n180^{\circ}-(n-2)180^{\circ}=360^{\circ}$. It follows that we can not have 4 or more obtuse exterior angles that is 4 or more acute interior angles.

Moreover, note there is a convex hexagon with angles:
$170^{\circ},170^{\circ},170^{\circ},70^{\circ},70^{\circ},70^{\circ}$.
Just glue three isosceles triangles with angles $170^{\circ},5^{\circ},5^{\circ}$ around an equilateral triangle (with side equal to the base of the isosceles triangles).

Comment: The sum of the interior angles of a *every* simple polygon of $n$ sides is $(n-2)\pi$.

Comment: @RobertZ Do you mean that maximum is n=6?

Comment: @Bimanifold Yes. Do you agree?

Comment: @RobertZ  Yes, I do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In comments, the OP indicates that interior angles of $180$ degrees are allowed, which makes things a bit trickier.  Please see my answer for more.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**:  If an interior angle is acute, the exterior angle is obtuse, and vice versa.

**Hint 2**:  What do the exterior angles of a convex polygon sum to?

**Added later**:  The answer to the OP's question can be $6$, $7$, or $\infty$, depending on the precise definitions of "convex" and "obtuse."

If the interior angles of a convex polygon are required to be *strictly* less than $180$ degrees, then the answer is $6$, as Robert Z's answer shows.

If interior angles of $180$ degrees are allowed, and these are considered obtuse (because $180\gt90$), then the answer is $7$:  Take, for example, a square, with $4$ right angles and designate any $3$ points along any of the sides of the square as additional vertices, each with an obtuse angle of $180$ degrees.  By Robert Z's argument (and/or the hints above), you can't do better than $7$.

Finally, if interior angles of $180$ degrees are allowed, but obtuse angles are required to be *strictly* between $90$ and $180$ degrees (which seems to be a [standard definition](http://www.mathopenref.com/angleobtuse.html) of "obtuse"), then you can take any convex polygon with three obtuse angles and designate as many more points as you please along the perimeter as additional vertices, each with a (non-obtuse!) interior angle of $180$ degrees.  In this case, there is no upper bound on the number of sides, so we can say the answer is $\infty$.

In comments, the OP indicated that convexity does allow for interior angles of $180$ degrees but did not specify whether they are considered obtuse.  In either case, the answer $6$ is technically wrong for this definition.